# Generate ranges between pairs of consecutive values

Tags: python

Say I have a list:

```
my_array = np.array([0, 5, 12, 18, 23])
```

I would like to generate a list of **ranges** between consecutive pairs of the list above, namely:

```
[range(0,5), range(5,12), range(12, 18), range(18, 23)]
```

Is there an easy way to build these ranges? Perhaps a more Pythonic way of doing it without explicitly looping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

## Python 2 variant:

```
>>> lst = [0, 5, 12, 15]
>>> map(range, lst[:-1], lst[1:])
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14]]
```

## Python 3 variant:

As in Python 3, `map`, `range` and many other functions do not return lists, but iterators, we may need to modify the call to get lists:

```
>>> list(map(list, map(range, lst[:-1], lst[1:])))
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14]]
```

But if you are fine with having list of range iterators:

```
>>> list(map(range, lst[:-1], lst[1:]))
[range(0, 5), range(5, 12), range(12, 15)
```

The Python 2 style return an instance of type `map`, what is something very close to an iterator:

```
>>> map(range, lst[:-1], lst[1:])
<map at 0x7faa5b15c6d8>
```

and you can:

```
>>> for itm in map(range, lst[:-1], lst[1:]):
       print (itm)
range(0, 5)
range(5, 12)
range(12, 15)
```

Comment: Note that this will behave a bit differently in Python 3 than your Python 2 demonstration shows. It *may* still work well enough for the questioner's needs, but it will be different. In Python 3, `map` is a generator and `range` returns an iterable object rather than a list.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

```
my_range = np.array([range(i, j) for i, j in zip(my_array[:-1], my_array[1:])])
# array([range(0, 5), range(5, 12), range(12, 18), range(18, 23)], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a useful function to return pairwise elements from a iterable, it get's fairly trivial.

```
import numpy as np 
from itertools import islice, tee

def pairwise(iterable, n=2):
    return zip(*(islice(it, pos, None) for pos, it in enumerate(tee(iterable, n))))

my_array = np.array([0, 5, 12, 18, 23])

myranges = [range(i,j) for i,j in pairwise(my_array)]

print(myranges)
#[range(0, 5), range(5, 12), range(12, 18), range(18, 23)]
```